# Keeping data together that are linked in a dataframe when only one is included in an API

Tags: python, dataframe, api

I am fairly new to Python so hoping to hear your thoughts on this scenario and question:

I have a dataframe with 1803 rows and 4 columns
Two of the columns are "Sequence" and "Gene names" from which the seqs derive.

My code for a loop that iterates over each seq for the IEDB API is working fine:

```
url = "http://tools-cluster-interface.iedb.org/tools_api/mhci/"
method = "netmhcpan_el"
allele = "HLA-A*02:01"
length = "9"
  
for index,row in df_SEQS.iterrows():
    sequence = (row["Sequence"])
    netmhcpan_el = {"method":method, "sequence_text":sequence, "allele":allele, "length":length}
    netmhcpan_el_resp = requests.post(url, netmhcpan_el_query)
    output_netmhcpan_el = netmhcpan_el_resp.text
```

But the output is a list of sequences that are no longer paired with their gene of origin.
How can I get the output to include sequence-gene pairs when the API does not have a variable for "Gene names" from the original df?
I've run out of ideas.

Thanks very much for any suggestions
LG

Comment: You say "get the output to include", but in your code, you overwrite the value of `output_netmhcpan_el` on every iteration of your loop. What output are you talking about exactly? Are you writing something to file and do you just want to write some of the original data to the file along with the response of the post? Or are you printing to the screen and want to do something similar there? Please provide an example of the output you're getting now, how you're creating that and how you want it to be different. (preferably an example of what you'd expect)

Comment: The output from this code is a string that looks like a table, which is then converted to a df via `pd.read_csv(StringIO(output_netmhcpan_el)`.  This df is the output I'm getting now, which contains a column with all of the sequences I am looking for. But what I need is output that contains not only this column of sequences, but also another column that contains the gene that each sequence came from. This is what I meant by "paired." Not sure any more clear now - if not I can try again to read help sections.

Comment: That does make it a bit clearer, but your code still has some odd things. For example, is `netmhcpan_el_query` really a typo and just `netmhcpan_el`? Can you share an example of `df_SEQS` or tell us where it's coming from? The answer to your question probably isn't that complicated, but my questions (and the lack of an answer) are cause by [not providing a mininmal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That article takes it a bit far, but the core idea is always the same: help people understand your exact situation and you get a (better) answer

Comment: Yes `netmhcpan_el_query` is my error and should be `netmhcpan_el`.  Here is df_SEQS as screenshot:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Xnn1OFzOIuGXLSVXiZOsks0ztcV1I-dg/view?usp=sharing   Apologies if not correct format - happy to send code but it's just pulling the viral protein sequences from uniprot and not entirely relevant to my question so did not include.  I checked the submission resource you suggested, but my question does not refer to a "bug" per se, so I am not seeing a way to offer a reproducible example.

Comment: FYI this df is sorted by Gene names so row #s not in order

Comment: Your question is still lacking some working code (even though you say "My code for a loop [..] is working fine" - clearly not the case, as it contains errors). You provided a link to an image of data in a comment, you should edit your question with essential information and [don't add data or code as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Thank you Grismar.  I'll take your comments back and work on the code a bit more and repost the question if still having trouble.

Comment: Please do @LauraGibson - I hope you see why the feedback is given, your questions are welcome, and hopefully whatever you add also gets you the answer you need. I'd be happy to give it a shot.